# iOS: Saving a double picker's settings (data persistence)

Tags: ios, persistence, uipickerview

So I have a double picker where the user sets each wheel to what they want, and then press a button which will display their choice. Easy clean and simple, but I want to store that data for later so that it does not disappear after they close the app and re-open it again. Now, I know how to do it with a datePicker, but not a doublePicker. So my question is how do I tweak my code from saving and retrieving a datePickers info into a doublePicker?

Here is my code for the datePicker:

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// Pulling the date out of my picker
NSDate *selectedDate = [self.datePicker date];

[defaults setObject:selectedDate forKey:@"DatePickerViewController.selectedDate"];
```

And then retrieving it again:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Get the date. I'm going to use a little shorthand instead of creating 
    // a variable for the instance of `NSUserDefaults`.
    NSDate *storedDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DatePickerViewController.selectedDate"];

    // Setting the date on the date picker. I'm passing `NO` to `animated:` 
    // because I'm performing this before the view is on screen, but after
    // it has been loaded.
    [self.datePicker setDate:storedDate animated:NO];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `UIPickerViewDelegate`:

```
        - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setInteger:row forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DoublePickerViewController.%i", component]];
}
```

To get the data out:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < doublePicker.numberOfComponents; i++) {
        NSInteger *storedInteger = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DoublePickerViewController.%i", i];
[doublePicker selectRow:storedInteger inComponent:i animated:NO];
    }
```

**For storing multiple values:**

In your `UIPickerViewDelegate`:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSArray *oldArray = [defaults arrayForKey:[NSString      stringWithFormat:@"DoublePickerViewController.%i", component]];

    //Make a mutable version so we can change it
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [oldArray mutableCopy];
    if (!newArray) {
        newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    //Add The Latest Row To The end of the array. We wrap it in an NSNumber so it can be in an array
    [newArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:row]];

    //If you want to have a limit on the amount of values that can be stored then use this
    int maxValues = 5;
    if (newArray.count >= maxValues) {
        //Remove the oldest object
        [newArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
    [defaults setObject:newArray forKey:[NSString      stringWithFormat:@"DoublePickerViewController.%i", component]];
}
```

To get the data out:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < doublePicker.numberOfComponents; i++) {
        NSArray *storedIntegers = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DoublePickerViewController.%i", i];
        //I don't know what values you want, but to get an int out of the array:
        //int integer = [(NSNumber *)[storedIntegers objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
        //And to set the row for a component:
        //[doublePicker selectRow:storedInteger inComponent:i animated:NO];
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I got a problem regarding where to integrate the first box of code. You say put it in the UIPickerViewDelegate, do you mean my delegate file? Because hat just creates hundreds of errors, and hen I implemented it in the buttonPressed method that the user presses to chose the picker values they have set it also gives me tons of errors. So could you be a bit more specific to where you put it? And tell me where to put the code in box two as well, please? Thank you very much :)

Comment: NVM, I got it to work bud. I put it in the UIPickerViewDelegate aka. under my #pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods. And the second code box was just missing a right hand bracket "]" thanks once again :)

Comment: I'm really sorry about all the spam, but I have a concern regarding your method. It saves the current picker values just fine, but when I change them it deletes the old values and saves the new once in its place. So is there any way that it saves the first values and if the user puts in a new value it saves that as well, without deleting the old values? So that everything that user puts the pickers to will be stored and can be brought back, and not just the most resent values. If you can help me with this it would be all, thanks again, as always :D

Comment: Yeah there might have been a missing ], because I wrote the code on the fly. If you want to store more than just the most recent value, then maybe you want to use an array.

Comment: I want to get a string out of the picker (array), not an integer.

Comment: We are storing the row number (integer) in the array, instead of whatever the row displays. You can just ask the `UIPickerViewDelegate` for a specific row or title with: `– pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` or `– pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:`

Comment: There seams to be something wrong with the method for storing multiple values. When I use that method my picker freezes in a weird way. If I try to change the picker by spinning the wheel and hit the button they just pop back to the two first once and select them for me. So the first method for one value works fine, except the fact that I need multiple values, but he multiple one seams to have a glitch. Any idea what might be the cause? It seams to me like the newArray is not working and I can't find anything wrong with the code. I feel like I'm so close to the solution, but I'm still so lost.

Comment: I just updated that part of my answer. I forgot to create an empty array if the defaults thing returns nil. See the new `if (!newArray)` in the answer

Comment: Ok I got good and bad news. Good news is that the new (!newArray) method fixed the problem with freezing the picker wheel. But the bad news is that the data stored that I try to access and then put out is frozen. Meaning that when I change the value of the wheel the value that is stored and then displayed does not change? Any idea what might cause this problem? Once again, I'm really sorry for bugging you so much, but I really don't know what to do. I believe it is related to the code in the last box. But I might be wrong, thx :)

Comment: So the are you using this line exactly or something different??? `int integer = [(NSNumber *)[storedIntegers objectAtIndex:0] intValue];`

Comment: If you are using that line exactly, you need to change it to `int integer = [(NSNumber *)[storedIntegers objectAtIndex:storedIntegers.count - 1] intValue];` to get the LATEST value. Remember from the setter code that we add the newest value to the END of the array.

Comment: If not, then log to make sure both of the sets of code are being called.

Comment: Is there a way I can contact you? I can't start a chat since I don't have enough points. I would like to send you a screen capture/recording of my problem, where I can explain in more detail and show you visually. Because it seams to me like you have a very good understanding of iOS dev. But you don't quite get what I'm asking for, after all it isn't exactly completely after the book the way I want to do this one thing. I just feel like if you knew exactly what I was in need for you could solve it quite simply. thx :)

Comment: I have an ok understanding, yes. However, I don't think there's a good way to contact me (Santa Claus has a very busy schedule). But if you can get 20 rep I can start a chat room that you can join and we can get this problem solved. You need only 4 more rep thanks to me :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35170/discussion-between-santa-claus-and-user2656615)